# Always keep printer hot and ready to print

Tags: prusa-i3

We are using a Prusa i3 MK2 printer in a structural design firm to print the buildings we design as well as print individual panels and components. Projects can have 100s of pieces that need to be printed quickly, but the printer cools of quickly after the print finishes. When we go to start the next print we have to wait 10-15 minutes for the printer to warm up again.

We tried preheating it using the built in function hoping that it would keep the heaters on after the print is complete but had no success.

Is there any way to set the printer to stay warm after the print to be able to quickly print back to back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set values in your end code for your slicer.  Set the bed to the temp you use, set the nozzle to roughly the Tg temp of the filament you use.  Typically the bed heatup time is the worst offender here.  I wouldn't keep the nozzle at extruding temps, though.

Comment: Depending on your slicer software, you should be able to find a location for setting end gcode scripts or sequences. Alternatively, you could create a simple gcode file containing only the needed commands and load it immediately after printing, then cancel it for the new print when ready.